# SQL Select based on certain Data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have a few tables in my database:

> 1. `user` table: `user_id (primary key)`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`.
> 2. `inst` table: `inst_id (primary key)`, `inst_name`, and `type`.
> 3. `user_insts` table: `user_insts_id (primary key)`, `user_insts_status`, `inst_name (foreign key)` and `user_id(foreign
>      key)`.

I'm using this on my website and i need it to display all of the entrys in the `inst_name` column for the `inst` table, but only the entrys for a certain id in the right side or else show as null. I've tried a few things like below:

```
SELECT inst.inst_name,inst.inst_id,user_insts.user_id,user_insts.inst_name 
FROM inst LEFT JOIN user_insts ON inst.inst_name=user_insts.inst_name;

SELECT inst.inst_name,inst.inst_id,user_insts.user_id,user_insts.inst_name 
FROM inst LEFT JOIN user_insts ON inst.inst_name=user_insts.inst_name 
WHERE user_insts.user_id='11';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT::

this is what i currently get:

```
 inst_name  inst_id user_id:
 ASB          1        11
 BNZ          3        11
 FMG          5        11
```

i was hoping to be able to get something more like this:

```
 inst_name  inst_id user_id:
 ASB           1       11
 ANZ           2      NULL
 BNZ           3       11
 paymark       4      NULL
 FMG           5       11
 STATE         6      NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by right-side, right-side of a join? Also what id in terms of your table fields are you referring to?

Comment: you are using left join and expecting right side result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your provided queries show the following results?

1. Query 1 : Shows all `inst` + `user_insts` entries but unfiltered by `user_id`
2. Query 2 : Shows just the `inst` + `user_insts` entries filtered by `user_id`

What's happening in Query 2 is that the `where` clause filters the joined tables AFTER they are joined. I guess what you want to happen is to first filter the right side of the result (`user_insts`) by a specific `user_id` like so:

```
SELECT ui.inst_name, ui.user_id FROM user_insts ui WHERE ui.user_id = :PARAM
```

Then, you want to LEFT JOIN this with all the entries in the `inst` table AFTER the filter. You could use an inner view in order to filter by `user_id` first before the actual joining to the `inst` table. The resulting query should be something like this:

```
SELECT i.inst_name, filtered_ui.user_id
FROM  inst i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ui.inst_name, ui.user_id
           FROM user_insts ui
           WHERE ui.user_id = :PARAM) filtered_ui
ON i.inst_name = filtered_ui.inst_name
```

Thinking about it more, I'm not too familiar with MySQL so I'm not sure if this alternative query is valid syntax:

```
SELECT i.inst_name, ui.user_id
FROM inst i
LEFT JOIN user_insts ui ON i.inst_name = ui.inst_name AND ui.user_id = :PARAM
```

... which may be simpler than an inner view.

The main point is you have to do the filtering first before joining, so that all the `inst_names` will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much :) this worked perfectly, the final query that you gave me, the one you where unsure about fixed the problem. Again thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What your original query will do is to get all rows from the `inst` table and then see whether there is a row that matches on `inst_name` in your `user_insts` table. If there is it will return the data from that table. Otherwise it will return NULLs. If you change the JOIN to be an INNER JOIN then it will only return rows where the right-hand side matches. Like this:

```
SELECT inst.inst_name,inst.inst_id,user_insts.user_id,user_insts.inst_name 
FROM inst INNER JOIN user_insts ON inst.inst_name=user_insts.inst_name 
WHERE user_insts.user_id='11';
```

But you should look at changing you schema. You have an integer primary key on `inst` so you should use that rather than `inst_name` as the foreign key on `inst_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't 100% clear so I'm making the assumption that you want to show the inst_name for each user; showing the inst_name as null when an inst entry doesn't exist.

Something like this should work:

```
select u.user_id, i.inst_name
from user u
left join user_insts ui on ui.user_id = u.user_id
left join inst i on i.inst_name = ui.inst_name
```

You can constrain the results by user_id by adding

```
where u.user_id = '11'
```